# Finding a value in JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

trying to check if the data is not empty

```
https://jsfiddle.net/1foj0y6t/
```

any idea?

```
var j = {
    "data": "solution",
  "sum":"100",
  "value":"500"
};

var obj2 = $(j).find("data").html();
console.log(obj2);
```

Comment: Please add more information. It's very unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: AFAIK: JQuery is only for HTML DOM. But your "j" is in Javascript (and not in the DOM). Therefore, it is unable to locate it.

Comment: `var obj2 = $(j).attr("data");` would be the correct syntax, however... it's kinda silly to use jquery for this. `var obj2 = j.data`

Answer (score 2):

You can just ask if `j.data` isn't `false`:

```js
var j = {
  "data": "solution",
  "sum":"100",
  "value":"500"
};

if (j.data) {
  console.log(j.data);
} else {
  console.log('no data!');
}
```

...or you can use it **like a array index** (bracket notation):

```js
var j = {
  "data": "solution",
  "sum":"100",
  "value":"500"
};

if (j['data']) {
  console.log(j['data']);
} else {
  console.log('no data!');
}
```

or **shorthand** version:

```js
var j = {
  "data": "solution",
  "sum":"100",
  "value":"500"
};

console.log(j.data||'no data!');
```

or by **declaration**:

```js
var j = {
  "data": "solution",
  "sum":"100",
  "value":"500"
};

let {data} = j;
console.log(data||'no data!');
```

Comment: `j['data']` is *not* an array index. It's property access via `bracket notation` and is primarily used for dynamic property access, or when the property name contains hyphens (i.e., `data-foo`). Also, what you're referring to as declaration is better known as "Object destructuring".

Comment: ok, so what if i do not have the `data : "solution"` in JSON, what additional check i can apply to see if it is defined or not yet

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that to check if `data` exists or not

```js
var j = {
  "data": "solution",
  "sum": "100",
  "value": "500"
};

const {
  data
} = j

const x = data || "empty"
console.log(x)
```